# Can I set a double from two integers?

Tags: java, double

I was wondering if it's possible to set a double from two integers, say:

```
int i = 1;
int j = 2;

double l = i.j;
```

so hopefully have l set to 1.2.

I'm currently trying this with a loop, but nothing is coming of it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    for(int l = 0; l < 8; l++){
        double piece = i.l;
            ChessSquare chessSquare = new ChessSquare(i, l, piece);
            int[][] square = new int[i][l];
            frame.add(chessSquare);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean ? You're trying to use a double to store the two ints ?

Comment: That does not seem to be a great place to use a `double`. What is its role in `ChessSquare`?

Comment: you could divide the second int by 10.0 and add it?

Comment: I'm not sure you've got the right idea of what the `double` type is.

Comment: I hope this isn't some kind of optimization attempt. What's the goal ?

Comment: In what possible sense is a chess piece a `double` value?

Comment: I am sorry, but in the present form the question makes little sense. What are you trying to do with `piece`?

Comment: If you're trying to save space, I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) an `int` is 4 bytes while a `double` is 8, saving you 0. If you're just trying to have the x-y location be one variable, there are ways to do that (like creating your own class, for instance).

Comment: or simply, as is often done, use 8*x+y and a one dimensional array.

Comment: This is a really strange misuse of data types. Don't use a `double` to store a chessboard location like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int i=1;
int j=2;
String s = i+"."+j;
double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
System.out.println(d);
```

How about this? I know `String` concat and stuffs will be pretty annoying(exceptions mainly), but certainly, this could help you out, if `i` & `j` are for sure gonna be numbers.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, although I don't understand where a double comes into play in a chess game:

```
int i = 1;
int j = 2;
double piece = i + j /  Math.pow(10.0 , String.valueOf(j).length())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 1;
int j = 2;

double l = i + j/Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(j) + 1));
```

For example:

```
int i = 1234;
int j = 56789;

double l = i + j/Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(j) + 1));

System.out.println(l);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1234.56789
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution:

```
double l = i + (j / 10d);
```

It works for values of j between 0 and 9 (10 > j >= 0);

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
int i = 1;
int j = 2;

double l = ((double)i*10+j)/10;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set two integer to one double you must go another way.

Try this instead:

```
int first = 1;
int second = 22;

double secondD = second;
while (secondD > 1) {
  secondD /= 10;
}

double firstD = first;
double result = firstD + secondD;
//result = 1.22
```

Comment: your while loop will return 0, change it to `secondD > 1`, and divide by 10.0 instead of 10

Comment: you still have to change `secondD /= 10` to `secondD /= 10.0`, dividing an int by an int will end up returning 0 still.

Comment: nope ... it works on my machine with 10 because secondD is Double http://ideone.com/56MhYC

Comment: my mistake, you're right, for some reason I was assuming secondD started as an int